# How to store logs of email notifications in laravel and store exception (if any failure occure while sending mail) at one place globally?

Tags: php, laravel, email, backend, helper

I'm creating one laravel webapp and sending bunch of emails through Mail helper function (code is given below), Now I want to store the log each mails including everything. i.e. email subject, recipients, bcc. in my local database to display admin. but at many places the mail helper function has used, but I want to achieve it at doing at only one place. Is it possible in laravel? see the code I'm using to send mail.

```
Mail::to($to)-\>cc($bcc)-\>send(new \\App\\Mail\\Mailer($maildata));
```

Comment: Laravel fires [a MessageSending/MessageSent event](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#events) whenever a mail is sent, so you can add an event listener to capture that data and store it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's built-in event system and logging system.

First, you need to define an event listener that will listen for the Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending event. This event is triggered just before the email message is sent, so it's the perfect place to log the email data.

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogSentEmails
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        $message = $event->message;

        $to = implode(', ', array_keys($message->getTo()));
        $cc = implode(', ', array_keys($message->getCc()));
        $bcc = implode(', ', array_keys($message->getBcc()));
        $subject = $message->getSubject();
        $body = $message->getBody();

        Log::info("Email sent to: $to; CC: $cc; BCC: $bcc; Subject: $subject; Body: $body");
    }
}
```

This event listener will log the recipient's email addresses, CC email addresses, BCC email addresses, subject, and body of the email message.

Next, you need to register the event listener in your EventServiceProvider.

```
protected $listen = [
        MessageSending::class => [
            LogSentEmails::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Finally, you can use Laravel's built-in logging system to log any exceptions that occur during email sending. You can define a Mail log channel in your config/logging.php:

```
'channels' => [
    // ...

    'mail' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/mail.log'),
        'level' => 'info',
        'days' => 14,
    ],

    // ...
],
```

Also log any errors in the following way:

```
try {
    Mail::to($to)->cc($bcc)->send(new \App\Mail\Mailer($maildata));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    \Log::channel('mail')->error($e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If Mail is PEAR's Mail:: interface, then ->send returns true on successfull delivery or false otherwise. If there are some errors in the mail communication, eg. related to malformed headers, you have a Pear Error.
Having this in your mind, you can access the Mail object and find what you need inside the object himself.

Check this little function as a starting points: it uses Mail Pear class

```
function send_generic_mail( $to = "", $subject = "", $body = "", $allegati = array(), $bcc = "" ) {
 require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/application/third_party/Mail.php";
 require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/application/third_party/Mail/mime.php";
 $headers = array (
    'From' => "{$this->config->config["website_name"]} <{$this->config->config["generic_email"]}>",
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject 
 );
if (trim( $bcc ) !== "") {
    $headers [ "Bcc" ] = $bcc;
}
/**
 * Configuration for ssl
 */
if ($this->config["mail_protocol"] == "ssl"){
    $socket_options =  array (
                "ssl" => array (
                "verify_peer" => false,
                "verify_peer_name" => false,
                "allow_self_signed" => true 
                ) 
            );
} else {
    $socket_options = "";
}
$smtp = Mail::factory( 'smtp', array (
        "host" => "{$this->config["mail_protocol"]}://{$this->config["mail_host"]}",
        "port" => "{$this->config["mail_port"]}",
        "auth" => true,
        "username" => "{$this->config["mail_username"]}", // your gmail account
        "password" => "{$this->config["mail_password"]}", // your password
        "debug" => false,
        $socket_options
) );
$nohtml = strip_tags( $body );
$mime = new Mail_mime();
$mime->setTXTBody( $nohtml );
$mime->setHTMLBody( $body );
// Attachments //
if (sizeof( $allegati )) {
    foreach ( $allegati as $file ) {
        $mime->addAttachment( $file->name, "application/octet-stream", $file->attach_name );
    }
}
$body = $mime->get();
// the 2nd parameter allows the header to be overwritten
// @see http://pear.php.net/bugs/18256
$headers = $mime->headers( $headers, true );
// Send the mail
$smtp->send( $to, $headers, $body );
return $smtp;
}
```

Comment: Laravel definitely doesn't use PEAR's Mail class.

Comment: @ceejayoz not exactly. The user tell us he use the "laravel Mail helper function" "but code is old", so I supposed he use "only" the helper, that is absolutelly possible. I use symphony/Mime in some project written with CodeIgniter....
So basically, one could use a piece of laravel into other projects and I suggested IF the main Email class/function he use is PEAR, THEN he could use my example as a starting point. Anyway the code i posted COULD be used as starting point, laravel or not

Comment: The user gave us their code - `Mail::to($to)->cc($bcc)->send(new \App\Mail\Mailer($maildata))` - which is very clearly Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#sending-mail).

Comment: @DanieleContinenza sorry man this is not something I'm looking for, I'm using simple laravel Mail helper function which I have stated in snippet.

Comment: kavan nopro. I have drawn the wrong conclusions based on information provided (or misunderstood)
@ceejayoz sorry again, it is NOT "very clearly Laravel". Method chaining isn't a prerogative of Laravel. Kakephp do the same with his Mail classes and \App\Mail\Mailer is NOT a prerogative of Laravel: swiftmailer is one of those using that sintax/structures

Comment: @DanieleContinenza "through laravel Mail helper function" is right there in the question. Between that statement, the Laravel tag, and the matching format, it's an entirely safe conclusion to make. It's also very clear from the code sample that OP wasn't using PEAR's Mail.

Comment: @ceejayoz it's getting boring...
He tells us that he's "building a webapp and sending a bunch of emails through laravel's Mail support feature". He didn't say that he is using laravel to create a webapp, he said that he creates a webapp and uses a laravel helper to send mails.
As just pointed out, I do exactly the same thing....I'm programming with CodeIgniter but using some from other frameworks like Symphony. There's nothing wrong with that and if you're good enough you'll solve a lot of problems without writing a line of code or nearly so...
That said, sorry I misunderstood the question